# dropbox login popup method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's probably jQuery, I just can't figure out how to do it. How do you get the login inputs to appear like that when you select login?

[dropbox website](http://dropbox.com)

Can someone give me possibly some demo code that they have describing the process? All i can think of is setting a div hidden and than showing it, am I wrong?

Comment: "I know it's probably jQuery" so Javascript equals jQuery now-a-days.. :)

Comment: Yes. All of my Javascript is jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right. And this is basically the only thing that happens.

I would do it on hover not on click. Its just a wasted click... 
and in this case you don't need any jQuery to do this.

Just hide the loginform and show it on hover.
Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/sXmAe/

if you really want it to happen on click, change all `:hover` to `:active`

Comment: You need click for accessibility.

Comment: you could add :focus for that

Comment: This is the correct answer. One questions, why not use click() instead of :active and :focus?

Comment: Actually, this isn't the solution. haha. :D

Comment: Reformulate your question then, or at least say why it is not the solution you are looking for. What is it, you want to know? My code does exactly what you question describes. But it does it without any JS. What is better in most cases. I don't use click() because you don't need it for this usecase.

Comment: but if you insist on a "complicated" less compatible version: http://jsfiddle.net/sXmAe/2/

Comment: Okay, I can't figure out the css solution. I have tried :focus and :active combos and haven't figured it out. I like that solution better. The js doens't even work because it just switches classes every click meaning that if someone were to click on an `input` box the div would go invisible.

Comment: Hey man, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309092/jquery-div-hide-show-on-focus-issue. I figured it out. If you could give me a working css example that would awesome!