# jquery: div hide/show on focus issue

Tags: jquery

Thanks to **inti's** code I was able to figure out the answer!

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(e) {
        //checks to see if the tag you clicked has the #login
        //div as a parent.
        if($(e.target).closest("#login").size() == 0) {
            //makes exception for the #login's <a> tag (id of a_login)
            if((e.target.id) == 'a_login') {   
                $("#login").show();
            } else {
                $("#login").hide();
            }
        //if target has #login as parent, keep it visible   
        } else {
            $("#login").show();
        }
    });

});
```

Working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/3CmE7/

Thanks!

---

I am trying to have a login screen similar to the http://dropbox.com login. Where a user clicks on the login link and a div appears (CSS) and when focus out, disappears.

Here is my jQuery

```
$('#login').bind('click', function() {
    $('#login').addClass("clicked").focusout(function() {
        $('#login').removeClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT:**

```
$('#login').click(function() {
    $('#login div').addClass("clicked").blur(function() {
        $('#login div').removeClass('clicked');
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `.blur()` not `.focusout()`.

**Edit:** click out of #mydiv to hide it:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#mydiv").size() == 0) {
        $("#mydiv").hide();
    }
});
```

This hides #mydiv if what you clicked doesn't have it as one of it's parents.

Comment: You should set the blur event on the input fields in the div. Also when you show the div, call .focus() on the input field you need to be focused.

Comment: But I don't want to have it so that the user HAS to select an input box for it to stay visible.

Comment: Also, if I want a link to "Create your account" in the div, I don't want to have it disappear when I try and click it.

Comment: Then you need something else. For example, to hide the div if the user clicks somewhere out of the box. I will add an example to my answer soon.

Answer (score -1):

I think you r looking something like this...

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a>

<div id="login">
    <label>Username:</label><input type="text"/><br/>
    <label>Password:</label><input type="password"/><br/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#login").hide();
    $('a').bind('click', function() {
        $("#login").toggle().focus();
    });
    $("input").focusout(function(){
        $("#login").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anish/ccFt9/1/

Comment: This doesn't work because when I select the 2nd input box, it disappears.