# How to do Dropbox Like Login Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, authentication, dropbox

I'm trying to do Dropbox like login button.
There was a thread [dropbox login popup method in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245859/dropbox-login-popup-method-in-jquery) but I couldn't do something on this. 
I want it to be opened when I press the login button same as dropbox.com

This is an example code. Now it works on hover. But I want on click. I tried focus but couldn't succeed.

```
<div id="login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <div>
        Login Form
        Lorem Ipsum blablbalbabababa lbablaabalbalba
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
div#login {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div#login:focus {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
div#login div {
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    visibility: hidden;
}
div#login:focus div {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This is the demo of this code http://jsfiddle.net/sXmAe/

Probably it is easier with Jquery but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply eliminate this rule:

```
div#login:focus div {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And then this piece of jQuery will make it visible on click:

```
$("#login a").click(function(){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

You can see it action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jPPew/2/

(I added a margin so the JSFiddle "Result" banner wouldn't get in the way of the click.")

EDIT: If you require that the behavior also "close" the login area if you click elsewhere, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jPPew/6/

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","visible");
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: Great. But now when I open it, it never closes. Like dropbox if I do mouse click on the background, login bar disappears.

Comment: @SnaRe Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jPPew/6/ (Note the different selector used. `#login` instead of `#login a`)

Comment: Thank you . This is what I'm looking for. But if you have time and if it is possible, can you optimize css. I think it is more complex then it should be. But if you have no time no problem. Thank you for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/sXmAe/50/